# sequencing asynctasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I understand that http requests should be run as part of an AsyncTask to keep it off the the UI thread.  But what about the case where multiple and sequential http requests may be necessary, where the latter http requests depend on the earlier, and therefore need to be run sequentially?

In this case, is it best to put the latter AsyncTasks in the onPostExecute of the earlier AsyncTasks, to make them run sequentially?

Or does this indicate that I have the wrong approach?

Comment: You might have better luck trying to make a Queue of HTTP requests inside an AsyncTask instead of many different AsyncTasks

Comment: hwrdprkns:  can you point me to any guidance on how a Queue of HTTP requests might be achieved?  Thanks.

Comment: See my answer, the code is a little much for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a lot of HTTPRequests in a queue, try this:

```
 private class QueueExample extends AsyncTask<URL, InputStream, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        SynchronousQueue<URL> queue = new SynchronousQueue<URL>();
        for(URL url : urls){
            queue.add(url);
        }

        for (URL url : queue) {
            InputStream in  = new BufferedInputStream(queue.take().openConnection().getInputStream());
            publishProgress(in);
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(InputStream... progress) {
        doSomethingWithStream(progress[0]);
        //Do Something
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //Finished
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to update the UI between requests, just execute them one after another in `doInBackground()` and accumulate the results. When done, just return and use the result in `onPostExecute()` to update the UI. If you do need to update the UI, you can call `publishProgress` when you get some intermediate result and update in `onProgressUpdate()`.